# Classes not being added or removed properly in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-waypoints, waypoint

Here is a piece of code in my project:

```
<script>
var $dipper = $('body');

$dipper.waypoint(function (direction) {
  if (direction == 'down') {
      $dipper.addClass('body2');
  } else{
      $dipper.removeClass('body2');
  }
}, { offset: '50%' });
</script>   

<style>
body {
  background-image: url("images/image2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 500px 200px;
  background-size: 800px 300px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


body2 {
  background-image: url("images/image1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 500px 200px;
  background-size: 800px 300px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>
```

As you can see from the javascript, I am trying to replace `image2`(located in `body`) with `image1`(located in `body2`) after I scroll halfway down the page, however, this is not happening. Currently `image2` appears next to a block of text and nothing happens as I scroll. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the problem that the class isn't being added, or that the style isn't being applied because your CSS is wrong? `body` is a valid CSS selector because it is a tag name but `body2` is not valid because it is not a tag name. Try changing `body2` to `.body2` in your `<style>` tag.

Comment: Oh wow, that was it. Thank you.